# Show that exactly half of the integers in the set are quadratic residues

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

> Let p be an odd prime. Show that exactly half of the integers in the set {1,2,...,p− 1} are quadratic residues.

Can somebody please dumb down the solution to this? I'm in the process of learning about modulo.

Thank you!

Comment: $x^2\equiv a^2\bmod p$ has exactly two solutions for $a\ne0$.

Comment: $\phi(x) = x^2$ is a surjective group morphism $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times \to ((\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times)^2$ and $\ker(\phi) = \{1,-1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Prelude

Let's look at the case $p=11$.

\begin{array}{|r|c|}
\hline
n \pmod{11}   & 1,10 & 2,9 & 3,8 & 4,7 & 5,6\\
\hline
n^2 \pmod{11} & 1    & 4   & 9   & 5   & 3 \\
\hline
\end{array}

So half of the $11-1=10$ integers in the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ are quadratic residues; which implies that the other half are not.

A proof for any odd prime number, $p$, must then require the following demonstrations for all $x,y \in \{1,2,3, \dots, p-1\}$.

> - $x^2 \equiv (p-x)^2 \pmod p$
> - $x \not \equiv p-x \pmod p$
> - If $x^2 \equiv y^2 \pmod p$ then $x \equiv y \pmod p$ or 
>     $x \equiv p-y \pmod p$

Proving the above will extablish that there are exactly $\frac 12(p-1)$ residues; and, hence, exactly $\frac 12(p-1)$ non-residues.