# Help proving half the integers in a complete residue system are quadratic residues

Tags: number-theory

The following theorem is what I need to prove:

> Let $p$ be an odd prime. Then half the numbers not congruent to $0$ in any complete residue system modulo p are perfect squares modulo $p$ and half are not.

I have done examples that help demonstrate this property:

> Consider the complete residue system $B=\{1,2,3,…12\}$ where for each value $B$ in we perform $f(b)=b^2 \space (\text{mod} \space 13)$
>
> $f(1)=(1)^2 \space (\text{mod} \space  13)=1$,   $f(2)=(2)^2 \space (\text{mod} \space 13)=4$, $f(3)=(3)^2 \space (\text{mod} \space 13)=4$,  $f(5)=12$, $f(6)=10$,  $f(7)=10$, $f(8)=12$,   $f(9)=3$, $f(10)=9$,   $f(11)=4$,   $f(12)=1$
>
> We see that $f$ maps all the values in the set $B$ to $F(B)=\{1,4,9,12,10\}$. This set $F(B)$ is our quadratic residues $a_i$. Now observe that only half the values in B exist in $F(B)$. This demonstrates what the theorem was discussing; that only half the integers in a complete residue system represent valid quadratic residues.

I can recognize the pattern but I'm at a complete loss for how to prove this theorem. Before anyone tries to close my question, yes, I have read other answer such as: [Show that exactly half of the integers in the set are quadratic residues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2502349/show-that-exactly-half-of-the-integers-in-the-set-are-quadratic-residues). But I don't understand the logic of the hint. I don't know how $x^2 \equiv (p-x)^2 \pmod p$ was formulated nor do I see how to use it to prove the theorem. Could someone help guide me through a full proof that deliberatly explains the logic of each step?

Please note I have absolutely no knowledge of Group Theory and I'd prefer to focus on a proof that doesn't use Primitive Roots (because I suck at primitive roots lol). Thank you for any help!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124675/discussion-on-question-by-bobby-b-help-proving-half-the-integers-in-a-complete-r).

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best explanatory approach is to consider my comments, following your question, against the specific example of $(p=11).$

First consider the values $\{1^2, 2^2, 3^2, 4^2, 5^2\}.$  **Is** it possible that two of those 5 values have the same residue, $\pmod{11}$?

Suppose that $a,b \in \{1,2,3,4,5\} ~: ~a \neq b.$
Further suppose that $a^2 \equiv_{11} b^2.$  
Then, $(a-b)(a+b) = (a^2 - b^2) \equiv_{11} 0.$

This implies that $11 ~| ~(a^2 - b^2) = (a-b)(a+b).$
However, by assumption, $a\neq b \implies 11 ~\not| ~(a-b).$ 
Further, by assumption, $1 \leq a,b \leq 5 \implies (a+b) < 11 \implies 11 ~\not| ~(a+b).$

Therefore, given that 11 is prime, the assumption that there exists $a,b \in \{1,2,3,4,5\} ~: ~a \neq b$ such that $a^2 \equiv_{11} b^2$ **has led to a contradiction**.

That is, you have that $11 ~| ~(a-b)(a+b)$, yet at the same time, it is impossible for $11$ to divide either $(a-b)$ or $(a+b)$.  Because $11$ is a prime, you know that whenever $11$ divides $(r \times s)$, then either $11 | r$ or $11 | s.$

As a result of this contradiction, I am free to conclude that $\{1^2, 2^2, 3^2, 4^2, 5^2\}$ represent $5$ **distinct** residues, $\pmod{11}.$

---

**Addendum**
The intent of the above analysis is to show that in general, $\{1^2, 2^2, \cdots, [(p-1)/2]^2\}$ **must** represent $[(p-1)/2]$ distinct residues, $\pmod{11}$.

The next step is to show, continuing to use $(p=11)$ as an example, that the exact number of quadratic residues must be $[(p-1)/2].$

Consider $6^2 = (11 - 5)^2 = 11^2 - [(2) \times (11) \times (5)] + 5^2.$ 
Clearly, from the above equation, you have that $6^2 \equiv_{11} 5^2.$ 
This implies that $6^2$ and $5^2$ **must** represent the exact same quadratic residue, $\pmod{11}.$

Now consider $7^2 = (11 - 4)^2 = 11^2 - [(2) \times (11) \times (4)] + 4^2.$ 
From the above equation, you have that $7^2 \equiv_{11} 4^2.$ 
This implies that $7^2$ and $4^2$ must represent the exact same quadratic residue, $\pmod{11}.$

Now consider $8^2 = (11 - 3)^2 = 11^2 - [(2) \times (11) \times (3)] + 3^2.$ 
From the above equation, you have that $8^2 \equiv_{11} 3^2.$ 
This implies that $8^2$ and $3^2$ must represent the exact same quadratic residue, $\pmod{11}.$

Now consider $9^2 = (11 - 2)^2 = 11^2 - [(2) \times (11) \times (2)] + 2^2.$ 
From the above equation, you have that $9^2 \equiv_{11} 2^2.$ 
This implies that $9^2$ and $2^2$ must represent the exact same quadratic residue, $\pmod{11}.$

Now consider $(10)^2 = (11 - 1)^2 = 11^2 - [(2) \times (11) \times (1)] + 1^2.$ 
From the above equation, you have that $(10)^2 \equiv_{11} 1^2.$ 
This implies that $(10)^2$ and $1^2$ must represent the exact same quadratic residue, $\pmod{11}.$

Therefore, you have that the quadratic residues represented by $\{6^2, 7^2, 8^2, 9^2, (10)^2\}$ **must be** the exact same $5$ quadratic residues as the residues represented by $\{1^2, 2^2, 3^2, 4^2, 5^2\}.$

Therefore, for $(p=11)$ there are exactly $5$ quadratic residues, among $\{1^2, 2^2, \cdots, (10)^2\}.$

This analysis easily generalizes to any odd prime $p$.

The foundation of this analysis is that if $a$ is any element in $\{1,2,\cdots, [(p-1)/2]\}$, then the following **two** things will be true.

- $(p-a)$ must be an element in $\{[(p-1)/2] + 1, \cdots, (p-1)\}.$
- $(p-a)^2 = p^2 - (2)(p)(a) + a^2 \equiv_{p} a^2.$

Therefore the $[(p-1)/2]$ quadratic residues represented by 
$\{\langle[(p-1)/2] + 1\rangle^2, \cdots, (p-1)^2\}$ 
must be the exact same quadratic residues as
$\{1^2, 2^2, \cdots, [(p-1)/2]^2\}.$

Therefore, for any odd prime $p$, there will be **exactly** $[(p-1)/2]$ distinct quadratic residues.

---

**Note**
Focusing on $(p=11)$, the quadratic residues are **not** represented by $\{1,2,3,4,5\}.$

Instead, the quadratic residues are represented by
$\{1^2, 2^2, 3^2, 4^2, 5^2\}.$

Comment: Okay. This helps a lot. So the first step to the proving the theorem is demonstrating that no two quadratic residues of a complete residue system are congruent. That is, we must prove $a^2 \equiv b^2 \space (mod \space p)$ is invalid for $a,b \in \{1,2,3,…,p-1\}$. The logic is from the idea that a complete residue system is only valid if each element is distinct to an element in the canonical residue system (i.e each integer must only be congruent to one remainder). So now that we know the complete residue system is valid for quadratic residues, how do we prove half are non-quadratic residues?

Comment: @BobbyB **No**!  You must prove that $a^2 \equiv b^2 \pmod{p}$ is **impossible** for $a,b$ distinct elements in $\{1,2,\cdots, [(p-1)/2]\}.$  As for the second part of your question, I will add an Addendum to my answer, and then flag you when it is ready.

Comment: Okay. I think I get where you're going. We divide the complete residue system into half it's elements $\{1,2,\cdots, [(p-1)/2]\}$ then prove that any two chosen elements will be incongruent modulo $p$. This demonstrates that each element of half the complete residue system is congruent to only one element of the canonical residue system. Since we are dealing with $x^2 \equiv a \space (mod \space p)$, the canonical residues (i.e. the remainder) are $a$, which is a quadratic residue.

Comment: Therefore, each element of complete residue system being congruent to the canonical residue systems means the elements of $\{1,2,\cdots, [(p-1)/2]\}$ represent the quadratic residues.

Comment: @BobbyB See the just added Addendum to my answer.

Comment: I can't understand this. I give up. I don't have the intelligence to follow the steps of your answer. Thanks for what help you did provide.

Answer (score -1):

Let me answer your queries in different manner.

$S_p = \{ 0, 1, \dots p - 1 \}$ *set of complete residues.*

---

$p - 1 \equiv - 1 \; (\text{mod } p)$

$p - 2 \equiv -2 \; (\text{mod } p)$

$\vdots$

$p - \frac{p -1}{2} \equiv - \frac{p-1}{2} \; (\text{mod } p)$

---

So we can rewrite our set of complete residues:

$- \frac{p-1}{2}, \dots, -1, 0, 1, \dots, \frac{p-1}{2}$

> Check that the new set also contains $p$ many elements.

---

Now, any square number can be thought as a bucket. Only $0$ goes to a bucket alone and others goes in pair $x$ and $-x$.